# Reduce amount of spinner items

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have a huge sqlite database (round a about 450 entries)

The user has to pick one of those.

Is there a way to create a textinput field which -after 3 characters are entered- turns into a spinner, where the only elements left are the ones with those charakters starting?

I guess i would have to make a View myself, right?

On the other hand i could make a textview above the spinner, and read it out when the user clicks on the spinner, but i wanted to make it "one" element...

Comment: Have you considered an `AutocompleteTextView` instead?

Comment: some answers are so simple... good damn it i had too much coffee and my brain is fuzzing complex problems and solutions =)

Comment: but another question, is it possible to deny a "false" entry which is not part of the autocomplete?

Comment: Not automatically (that i know of). You'd have to check it later.

Comment: but this looks way easier than what i thought first of =) thank you a lot!

Comment: @tsrac and the easiest way to work with it is to use a CursorAdapter plus FilterQueryProvider